# GeoServer BlobStores wont save. An error occures

Tags: geoserver, error, geowebcache

I just created a new BlobStore and it gives me an error when I save it.

[[image: BlobStore confBlobStore Error]

Comment: What error do you get? What does the log file say

Comment: Sorry, I thought i uploaded even error image. Error as below:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1@641bfd47 on component [SaveLink [Component id = save]] threw an exception
 at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)